# setInterval acting odd in webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit, setinterval

I'm working on a dashboard for a website, and one of the final features I'm adding is a clock. I have a basic function that gets the date/time, formats it, and outputs it into a clock, but my `setInterval` function isn't working in Webkit browsers. I've tried re-arranging it a few different ways with no success.

In Webkit, the clock will reload if I force it to re-render by highlighting the clock text, or scrolling, etc.

My code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    setInterval(function() {

        var time = new Date();

        var hour = time.getHours();
        var min = time.getMinutes();
        var sec = time.getSeconds();
        var amPm = (hour < 12 ? "AM" : "PM");

        hour = (hour <= 12 ? hour : hour - 12);
        min = (min < 10 ? "0" + min : min);
        sec = (sec < 10 ? "0" + sec : sec);

        var currentTime = (hour + " : " + min + " : " + sec + " " + amPm);

        $('#time').html(currentTime);


        var date = time.getDate();

        var month = time.getMonth();

        var year = time.getYear();

        year = year - 100;

        var todaysDate = (month + "/" + date + "/" + year);

        $('#date').html(todaysDate);


        var dayNum = time.getDay();

        var day = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");

        $('#day').html(day[dayNum]);


    }, 1000);

});​
```

It works in Firefox, but not in Chrome or Safari. Does anyone know why `setInterval` behaves strangely in Webkit, and what the fix is?

Comment: what's the code for the //Clockwork?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt realize the clock code was relevant given its full functionality in firefox, but here it is anyway.

Comment: From the sounds of it, the error has something to do with Chrome not redrawing a portion of the screen which has updated. You can verify that `setInterval` is doing its job by placing a `console.log('tick')` inside the function, and watching your console.

Comment: I did that at first, and it would appear that it was working as fast as possible, because within seconds my console had over 5000 'check's

Comment: Your code works fine for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/jRUM8/

Comment: Same here, the fiddle by @FelixKling is working fine in Chrome. Is that all your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out, there were a few bugs in my code. One being that the time object needs to be declared globally. Also, the best syntax is to wrap the whole thing into one function called `updateClock()` and then use the `setInterval` on that, without `()` after the function

```
setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
```

Good Luck